# New user unable to see database they have access to in phppgadmin

Tags: postgresql

I'm mostly a command-line user of PostgreSQL myself, but for others I've recently had cause to set up a PHPPGAdmin frontend.

However, I've run into a problem - while on the command line users have no problem logging in and connecting to the database they're supposed to have access to, in the PHPPGAdmin frontend they're not able to see the databases they don't own (but have read access to).

I have tried the following:

```
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE example TO otheruser;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO otheruser;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO otheruser;
```

As said before, when using software or direct command line connection this is sufficient to let them connect and SELECT from the database; the problem seems to be with PHPPGAdmin.

Any suggestions as to what I may be overlooking are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, did some digging into the source code and what I overlooked was in `config.inc.php`:

```
// Only show owned databases?
// Note: This will simply hide other databases in the list - this does
// not in any way prevent your users from seeing other database by
// other means. (e.g. Run 'SELECT * FROM pg_database' in the SQL area.)
$conf['owned_only'] = true;
```

Changing this from `true` to `false` solved the problem.

Comment: this is not nice, because the user then can see structure of tables of databases of other users

Comment: instead, change ownership of the database with ALTER DATABASE name OWNER TO new_owner;

Comment: @Palo Please re-read my question -- I was specifically looking for a way to enable them to see tables *they do not own but do have read access to*.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It helped me though to understand that the structure of the tables in databases of other users are accessible - not only through phppgadmin, but also from other clients, I was not aware of that. Thanks.